# how to upload,download, or delete a directory or multiple files in FTP server using CFNetwork?

Tags: ios4, upload, ftp, directory, cfnetwork

i have starting learning about FTP Programming, i learn some from [simpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html) that using CFNetwork. From this sample i understand how to upload and download a file from ftp server, and also i understand how to get a list file and directory from FTP server. But the problem is, i want to upload, download, and delete a directory or multiple files in FTP server, but i dont know how to do. Can somebody give an example? Can i do it using CFNetwork? Or am i have to add another library for doing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it will help u

http://code.google.com/p/s7ftprequest/

or

http://www.ftponthego.com/

you could use cURL if you have little success with the apple sample code, see here.

http://www.intelliproject.net/articles/showArticle/index/use_curl_iphone_sdk

Comment: thank you for your answer madhu, but on s7ftp, the link says that it can do Upload and Create directory operations, but not yet for download and delete directory.
I have try to do what that last link says, but it give me thousands error, can you give me another clue?